# Can I give an author access to google analytics plugin in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want all authors in wordpress to be able to see and access the google analytics plugin.However, when I access the google analytics pages of the plugin, i get "Vous n’avez pas les droits suffisants pour accéder à cette page." ['You haven't sufficient rights to access this page'] error.. How can i make all authors access this page ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics isn't aware of WordPress accounts -- it doesn't know the difference between your authors and a hole in the ground. You will need to explicitly add their Google accounts to have access to your Analytics panel.